# How to resolve a JDBC Connection authorization failure. Reason: User ID revoked

Tags: jdbc, db2, aix

Using the simplest possible Java program to connect to a remote DB2 database, I get the following error, connecting from client 9.245.63.34 to server 9.244.43.32:

```
root@9.245.63.34 # java -classpath /software/jars/IBM/db2jcc.jar:/software/jars/IBM/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:. DatabaseConnector
com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.SqlException: [ibm][db2][jcc][t4][2017][11253] Connection authorization failure occurred.  Reason: User ID revoked.
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.m(b.java:2010)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.c(b.java:1655)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.bb.r(bb.java:792)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.bb.k(bb.java:349)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.bb.c(bb.java:133)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.zc(b.java:1279)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.b(b.java:1200)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.y(b.java:4597)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.b(b.java:754)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.a(b.java:697)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.a(b.java:378)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.b.<init>(b.java:316)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:174)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:675)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
        at DatabaseConnector.main(DatabaseConnector.java:29)
```

The Java program looks like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DatabaseConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load the DB2 JDBC driver
        try {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        // Define database properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("user", "dbuser");
        properties.put("password", "SecretPa55word!");

        // JDBC URL for Mediator_Control_DB
        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:db2://9.244.43.32:50010/MYDB";

        // Establish the database connection
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, properties)) {
            System.out.println("Connected to the database.");

            // Execute a sample query
            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1");
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    String currentDate = resultSet.getString(1);
                    System.out.println("Current date from the database: " + currentDate);
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The error seems related to the DB2 user on the host AIX system being used to connect, dbuser, whose password expired. The password was reset on the host through:

```
root@9.244.43.32 # passwd dbuser
```

But the error persists.

On the host system, the user also has the following attributes that seem relevant to the error:

```
root@9.244.43.32 # lsuser -f dbuser 
        loginretries=5
        account_locked=false
        unsuccessful_login_count=0
```

Please advise.

I tried reseting the password multiple times, as well as clearing the unsuccessful_login_count attribute of the user on AIX through:

```
root@9.244.43.32 # chsec -f /etc/security/lastlog -a unsuccessful_login_count=0 -s dbuser
```

Comment: Is dbuser able to login interactively to the remote Aix with those credentials (assuming interactive login is permitted for that account)?  Separately, double check in the Db2-server diagnostics that the account-name that is revoked  __really__ is dbuser.  Also check that Db2 database is not configured to revoke connect authority from that dbuser (ask your DBA or your secadm if you have one).

Comment: We got past this error. Thanks.